# Is the Image of a Lie Group Action on a Submanifold also a Submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group acting on a compact manifold $M$. Let $S \subset M$ be a compact embedded submanifold. Then is
$$G \cdot S = \{ g.s \in M : g\in G, s \in S \} $$
an embedded submanifold of $M$?

I know that this is true if $S$ is equal to a single point, however I could not find a general statement for when $S$ is a submanifold. If this is true, could you please provide a reference?

Comment: It's not. Try to construct a counterexsmple for S^1 (rotational) action on S^2.

Comment: Funnily enough, I had used that example to make me think that the statement could be true. But now I can see the counterexample. A circle slightly angled to the horizontal plane will be a sub-manifold of $S^2$, but its orbit will be a closed strip in $S^2$ which is not a manifold. Thank you.